# Именование методов доступа к данным в Clean Architecture

Tags: java, android, архитектура

Можно ли мыслить в терминологии конкретного источника данных (например, базы данных) в Presentation (Presenter) и Domain (Interactor) слоях? Для примера: может ли presenter вызывать у interactor'a метод `saveAccountInDB()` или правильнее будет `saveAccountInRepository()`?

---

Вопрос: стоит ли скрывать фактический источник данных в методах доступа к ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Нельзя раскрывать истинный источник данных.

---

Презентер занимается только перенаправлением данных в нужный интерактор и ничего не знает о какой-либо логике\источнике. Правильнее будет вызвать  у интерактора метод `saveAccount(...)`. Интерактор же общается с репозиторием, а репозиторий не должен рассказывать о источнике данных. От сюда выходит, что и интерактор вызывает метод `saveAccount(...)` у репозитория.

---

Однако, исключением являются репозитории, которые работают с кэшем и которые должны давать возможность загрузить данные из него. Тогда интерактор знает о том, что репозиторий умеет работать с кэшем (а, следовательно, и сетью).